# Get an embeddable link from a public Facebook post's link

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

### Question

Is it possible to get a permalink, which can be embedded successfully, to a facebook post from a link that follows the form `https://www.facebook.com/{REFERENCED_PAGE_ID}/posts/{SOME_OTHER_ID}` instead of the typical form `https://www.facebook.com/{POSTER_ID}/posts/{POST_ID}`? If so, how can it be done?

### Background

Given a link such as the following (which cannot be embedded properly)
https://www.facebook.com/209447300380/posts/10153494075900381

I need to be able to programmatically produce the following link which can be embedded
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151668558417282&set=a.244117472281.146601.8128837281&type=1

Normally the solution would be to query facebook with the statement

```
select permalink from stream where post_id='209447300380_10153494075900381'
```

However this query does not produce any data for me. My suspicion is that there is a problem with the original link:  `209447300380` is not the ID of the posting page, but rather, the ID of the page being referenced. In cases where `209447300380` is the ID of the posting page, I can get a permalink from Facebook without any problems.

### Miscellaneous Details

- I am using an application access token with the read_stream permission. It may be the case that I do not have sufficient permissions; I'm not sure.
- I'm also having issues getting a permalink for user posts (posts not posted by official 'pages'). I don't know if this is relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately we've found the most reliable way to figure out the embeddable link is simply to try to access the starting link, and then follow where it redirects to. If the redirects end at facebook.com/login, then it isn't embeddable (to the public, anyway). Otherwise, the embeddable link should eventually be reached.

C# Sample:

```
public static string GetPermalink (string url) {
  HttpWebRequest request;
  HttpWebResponse response; 

  request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create (url);
  request.Method = "HEAD";
  request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
  request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1304.0 Safari/537.16";

  try { response = request.GetResponse () as HttpWebResponse; }
  catch (WebException ex) { response = ex.Response as HttpWebResponse; }

  using (response) {
    string responseUri = null == response.ResponseUri ? null : response.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri;

    if (HttpStatusCode.OK == response.StatusCode) {

      /* Ended at a login page. This post isn't viewable to the public. */
      if (responseUri.StartsWith (@"https://www.facebook.com/login.php?") ||
          responseUri.StartsWith (@"http://www.facebook.com/login.php?")) {
        return null;
      }

      /* Found a public post. */
      else return responseUri;
    }

    else return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: That said, this method is still not full-proof. EX: https://www.facebook.com/100007404516120/posts/1401551816768289

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a bug. Getting the permalink using FQL doesn't work whereas it works with Graph API. You should use Graph API then:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/209447300380_10153494075900381?fields=link&access_token=YOUR_TOKEN
```

Result:

```
{
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151668558417282&set=a.244117472281.146601.8128837281&type=1", 
  "id": "209447300380_10153494075900381", 
  "created_time": "2013-11-08T18:08:46+0000"
}
```

Using the Graph API won't do too much changes in your app, I guess.

Comment: Using that URL comes back with an error for me. 

{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request.",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}

Comment: +Stéphane Bruckert, Are you doing any authentication with that call?

Comment: Sure, you should authenticate. Use it in the [Graph API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) or add a token at the end of the URL: `&access_token=TOKEN`. You can use the same token as for your FQL queries. Also use `https://`.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for facebook page posts with links, such as [this one](https://www.facebook.com/68680511262/posts/10152299388379155). Instead, FB returns a link to nfl.com. :L @Stéphane Bruckert

Comment: Sorry @Amanduh, I don't see your point here. What do you exactly expect to get from [this link](https://www.facebook.com/68680511262/posts/10152299388379155)?

Comment: If you run 68680511262_10152299388379155 through the graph query it returns a link to nfl.com. @Stéphane Bruckert

Comment: I know. What are you **expecting** as a result? Because you say it doesn't work, what  result would let you say that "it works"? In your initial post, you asked to get [this kind of link](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151668558417282&set=a.244117472281.146601.8128837281&type=1) from [this link](https://www.facebook.com/209447300380/posts/10153494075900381). Now, what do you want to get from [this link](https://www.facebook.com/68680511262/posts/10152299388379155)?

Comment: Sorry, I'm expecting the embeddable link "https://www.facebook.com/NFL/posts/10152299388379155". I can get this link via FQL, but if the URL is convoluted enough, I believe neither the FQL query above nor the graph API method will work. @Stéphane Brucker